# MacBook unplugged from external monitor thinks it's still the Secondary Desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've got a MacBook Pro 13" with Lion plugged into an external VGA monitor.  Often, when I unplug its video dongle deal, the MacBook doesn't realize the other monitor is gone.  It continues to believe it's the Secondary Monitor (which I can confirm by right-clicking the desktop and selecting "Change Desktop Background...").

There's no menu bar, so I can't get to my Display icon to Detect Displays.  No, I don't want the MacBook screen to be the primary when I'm on the external.

Plugging the DisplayPort dongle back in does nothing.  It won't even re-display on the external monitor it was hooked up to before, so no mirroring kludge if I forget.  To this point, I hard power down and restart.

Any idea how to tell the MacBook there's no external monitor and that it's the primary now?

Comment: Command + Brightness Up is the keyboard shortcut for Detect Displays, but that option is gone now in ML.

Comment: @vcsjones he said he is on Lion, which should clear his problem!

Comment: @vcsjones -- might want to turn that into an answer.  Seems to do the trick in 10.7.

Comment: @ruffin Added as answer.

Comment: this is happening to me in big sur 11.3.1

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Command + Brightness Up is the keyboard shortcut for Detect Displays in Lion.

Comment: On my MBP with ML, It turns out that Option + Brightness-Up turns on detect displays.

Comment: Jumping into this conversation 2.5 years later (HELLO PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE) to say that this also works a treat in Yosemite.

Comment: Have been getting this in El Capitan and Option+Brightness-Up helped me to get into the Settings window (which itself was difficult before as explained by ruffin's comment). I got the option to gather all windows, but that didn't make any difference, and Mac continued to behave like there is an external monitor. I was clicking on random options to see if it helps, and when I clicked on "Mirror displays" option, my display became blank and soon Mac itself crashed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a 2016 MacBook Pro that has a Touch Bar instead of brightness controls?

Comment: Jumping in 6 years later...It still works in Mojave. This works like a charm!!

Comment: 2018 MBP touchbar with 10.13.6 High Sierra wouldn’t turn display on, touchbar prompted to mirror or extend.  I picked mirror thinking it would turn on the built in display but it didn’t.  Searching on my phone found this, which did reactivate the display, but left everything blurry.  Preferences / Displays showed one display, Resolution was set to “Scaled”; switching it to “Default” partly fixed the blurryness but left some windows only rendering half of their content.

Comment: And since "Brightness Up" might be a "Function+F2", the shortcut *might* be Option+Fn+F2.

Comment: ✅ Big Sur (even with a touchbar) Option + Brightness Up opens Display Settings. I had to select "Resolution: Scaled" and temporarily choose a new size for the display to go back to normal.

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.3.1 putting it to sleep then waking it up worked for me.  Phantom display gone, windows in their correct positions.

Comment: Works with macOS Ventura 13.4.1. Go StackExchange! Even Apple support website doesn't have this simple answer (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7040158) They say to reboot

Answer (score 38):

Another way to do this is by going to **Displays** in **System Preferences** and then holding down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key and the **Gather Windows** button will turn into a button that says **Detect Displays**.

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer isn't much help if you have a Windows-style keyboard connected...

Comment: This answer is obviously working for some folk, but in my original situation, you couldn't get to Settings. You could open it, but the Mac thinks it's displayed on the now-missing "primary display". /sigh @JamesB -- Fwiw, since the question is about a MacBook, and it's difficult to take the Mac keyboard off ;^D, the accepted answer works great. Would be a pain if what I'm seeing happened on an iMac, though it sounds like you're seeing something different.

Comment: I had this problem on an iMac, yes.  We don't want the kids wrecking our "nice" wireless aluminum keyboard so we have a cheap Windows USB KB hooked up for day to day use.

Comment: This works well on machines with a touch bar.

Comment: I have unplugged ant tried this, but osx still thinks my 5k is plugged in… Pretty damn annoying bug. Do I have to reboot?

Answer (score 17):

I've had this with Mavericks a few times, and I found out that in my case changing the *Rotation* will trigger the OS to recognise the monitor(s) aren't there. Changing the resolution or some other action (besides obvious reboot) didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Oh thank god, it works in Yosemite too.  If I could buy you a beer, I would.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty cool. Also worked for me. What a hack.

Comment: **I had the issue on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 on a rMBP. And this hint worked!** All other hints presented in this issue failed: "Detect Displays" via "CMD + Brightness Up" did nothing. "CMD + Brightness Down" showed the external screen content on the internal screen, the same keystroke again switched back to internal display. System Preferences > Displays: Hold down ALT so that the button "Gather Windows" change into "Detect Displays" and then clicking it, also failed.

Comment: Nevertheless the discrete GPU remained active, and only a restart switched back to integrated graphics.

Comment: This works on the High Sierra beta as well (in my case it's a HDMI monitor).

Answer (score 12):

None of the other options worked for me on my El Capitan MBP, but putting it to sleep and waking it up immediately worked like a charm.

Comment: This has been my workaround, however 30% of the time the Macbook doesn't wake up (must power cycle) and I lose all my SSH sessions, and have to recover unclosed vi sessions. My company issues us 13" laptops for development (Mac or PC), but I'm about ready to use my own money to buy a 17" Lenovo running Ubuntu (at least then, it'll also fix my terminal hotkeys like control-d back-word navigation)

Comment: This solution no longer works on Catalina :( Help pls!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, (though I'm using the HDMI port on my 13 inch MacBook Pro Retina to run my external monitor - the overheating and wifi interference hassles with Thunderbolt that drove me to use the HDMI port are for another thread...) and have, thus far found that powering down the monitor I'm using (a Dell 4K HD powered by a 110 appliance plug) then waiting a minute or so before unplugging the HDMI connector from my MBP usually sends the right message to the computer and gets me back to the single screen.